# Android: fixed warnings still visible in eclipse res/values

Tags: android, eclipse, android-lint

I just revised my `res/values-folder`, because there where values not used, and consequently there was a warning telling me that.

Now that I "cleaned" the unused ones, the warnings are still visible. First I rebuilt the project a few times, restarted eclipse and finally rebooted my pc, but nothing seems to effect on that.

For example my `colors.xml` file

[image]

As you can see, there is no value "background" anymore. Same thing with the other warning claiming that the value "black" is not used, and same thing for about 20 values in strings.xml. Is there a trick to fix this?

Comment: Re-run lint: Rightclick on Project - Android Tools - Run Lint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to latest ADT. Some lint processing issues have been fixed in ADT 20.0.2 only, which previously lead to wrong warnings/errors remaining in the project. Additionally check that "Build automatically" is checked in the Project menu, as those unused resource warnings can only be updated on a project build, not on saving the XML editor (while many other warnings are updated on saving).

Comment: "Build automatically" is activated, in fact, developing android without this option can be very frustrated :-). But my ADT need an update indeed!